# Bug in iOS5, but working in iOS6

Tags: objective-c

receiving this error when running in iOS5 simulator:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1497052 0x1286d0a 0x13d680b 0x13eee39 0xf92d 0x3f49d6 0x3f58a6 0x404743 0x4051f8 0x3f8aa9 0x1d5efa9 0x146b1c5 0x13d0022 0x13ce90a 0x13cddb4 0x13cdccb 0x3f52a7 0x3f6a9b 0xf15d 0x2405)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

It crashes on launch. :@

I've been using breakpoints, and i think (not sure) that it maybe something to do with this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

Complete app delegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    Reachability* internetReach;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation *currentLoc;

@end
```

Thanks, help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show more detail of your code? We can identify more. Thanks

Comment: That line shouldn't be throwing an error in either SDK. Perhaps you haven't used @synthesize in the implementation? It's not required in iOS6 but is in iOS5. Also, if I was you I'd move that kind of code away from the AppDelegate into another class.

Comment: Added more above, many thanks.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace, too?

Comment: I have synthesised...
`@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize currentLoc;`

Comment: @sqreept what is the stack trace buddy?

Comment: The list functions called to get to the point where your error happens.

Comment: The message says it all: you're inserting a nil object. What elße do you need?

Comment: @AdamWaite, the synthesize satement is not needed for any iOS version. it depends on the compiler that is used —> it doesn't matter for which version you write the code, as long the compiler is a recent one.

Comment: I am new to obj c, so forgive me if im a noob. Where would i be inserting a nil object, any clues?